# How do I get this equation into a 3D graph in Matlab, it gives me this error every time

Tags: matlab, 3d

This is my code:

```
C=15*10^-6;
L=240*10^-3;
V=24;
R=10:0.01:40;
W=60:0.01:110;
I=V/(R.^2+((W*L)-(1/(W*C))).^2).^0.5;
axes(handles.axes3)
plot3(R,W,I)
```

And this is where it what the error message says:

> Error using  /
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in Homework9GUI>pushbutton3_Callback (line 110)
>   `I=V/(R.^2+((W*L)-(1/G)).^2).^0.5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `./` insteads of `/` - that is, element-wise division instead of matrix division.

```
I=V./(R.^2+((W*L)-(1./(W*C))).^2).^0.5;
```

Comment: well when i change it to that i get this error:
    Error using  + 
    Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: @user3065129 you must make sure `R` and `W` has **exactly** the same size

Comment: The same size? could you give me an example?

Comment: @user3065129 your `R` has 3001 eleemnts: `size(R)` gives `[1 3001]`. However, your `W` has 5001 elements: `size(W)` gives `[1 5001]`. These two must have **exactly** the same number of elements and `size`.